# How can I use the SIGAR Library in Java to get a class cpu and memory usage?

Tags: java, sigar

I have been struggling for hours with this.
How can I find the cpu and memory usage of a class using the SIGAR library in Java.

Comment: Can you give an example of a bit of code you tried?

Comment: I don't believe that you can get class-level statistics using sigar.